# Resize Svg Image Using Jquery on Button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, svg, jquery-plugins

Hi i see the code for resize svg image  using jquery .Please see this

```js
$('.resize').resizable({
    ghost: true,
    resize: function( event, ui ) {
     var width = ui.size.width;
      var height = ui.size.height;
      $('image').attr('width',width);
      $('image').attr('height',height);
    }
            });
            
var position = $('svg').position();
$('.resize').css('top',position.top);
$('.resize').css('left',position.left);
```

```css
.resize{
  height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="resize">
resize helper
</div>
  <div class='resize-plus'></div>
<div class='resize-minus'></div>

<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="800" height="420" id="svg">
    <image height="120" width="120" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="http://designpieces.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/chrome.png" ></image>
</svg>
```

Now i have  div's with class resize-plus ,resize-minus
.If we click on resize-plus i need to increase the size of svg , if resize-minus  i need to decrease the size of svg.That is resize functionality need to amend in these two divs.
So how to do that ? and how to set condition like if image size increse greter than and less than in resize .
Thank you .

Comment: Give your SVG a viewBox, decrease the size of the viewBox to zoom in and increase it to zoom out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added functions for `+` and `-` divs.

Check out below fiddle:

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/m9c771LL/79/)